# Uploading Large Images/Layers to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am attempting to push a docker image to ECR with a layer that is roughly ~5gb in size (anchore/inline-scan image). The smaller layers are pushed successfully, but the large layer times out when attempting to push, and will continually retry. I am assuming this is because the max layer size of ECR is being exceeded.

How can I upload a large image layer to ECR?

Comment: try to break down the larger layer into smaller ones. That is the beauty of layering that it facilitates transfer and usability.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your image into many more, smaller layers. The [ECR service quotas docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/service-quotas.html) says:

> The maximum layer size is *10,000 MiB*, calculated by multiplying the maximum layer part size of *10 MiB* by the maximum number of layer parts *1,000*.

Comment: I have several layers as part of the same image. How would I push them together to a private ECR repo? The goal is to deploy to EKS.

Answer (score 0):

## 2024 March 30th

> **Maximum layer size** = 52,000 mebibytes [54,525 megabytes]
>
> This quota is not adjustable
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/service-quotas.html